# Get value from <select> (dropdown) in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to show more input when "married" option is selected. I tried this.

```js
    const [single, setsingle] = useState(false);
    const [married, setmarried] = useState(false);
    
    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option
            value={single}
            name="single"
            onChange={(e) => {
                setsingle(e.target.value);
            }}
        >
            محرد
        </option>
        <option value={married} name="married"
            onChange={(e) => {
                setmarried(e.target.value)}}
        >
            متاهل
        </option>
    </select>

    {married === "married" ? <Wife /> : null}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few basics/fundamental things which you need to correct in your code:

1. You need to put `onChange` inside `<select>`, **not** inside `<option>`.
2. You have created single and married as boolean and then comparing it as string value.
3. You are always setting the value `false`.
4. You can't use `class` inside any JSX elements. Instead of class, you must use `className` for setting the CSS classes.

Your code should look like this:

```js
const [single, setsingle] = useState(false);
const [married, setmarried] = useState(false);

...

return (
    <>
        <select className="form-select"
            aria-label="Default select example"
            onChange={e => {
                const selectedValue = e.target.value;
                if(selectedValue === "single") {
                    setsingle(true);
                    setmarried(false);
                } else {
                    setsingle(false);
                    setmarried(true);
                }
            }} 
        >
            <option value={"single"} name="single">
                محرد
            </option>
            <option value={"married"} name="married">
                متاهل
            </option>
        </select>
        {married && <Wife />} {/* here since married is boolean, you can directly use it like this, or you can use {married === true ? <Wife /> : null} */}
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this to manage the status in one variable. also, onChange event should be in `select`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);

  function changeStatus(e) {
    setStatus(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select value={status} onChange={changeStatus}>
        <option value="single">Single</option>
        <option value="married">Maried</option>
      </select>
      {
        status === "married" && <Wife />
      }
    </div>
  );
}


const Wife = () => {
  return <div>
    <input placeholder="Please enter name" />
  </div>
}
```

Working sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-shamir-3k17b